# Как установить часовой пояс в datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Есть функция для получения времени

```
def get_current_time() -> datetime:
    return datetime.now()
```

Я пытался сделать так, чтобы всегда был установлен Московский часовой пояс, где бы ни был запущен скрипт, получилось как то так:

```
def get_current_time() -> datetime:
    delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=3, minutes=0)
    datetime.now() = (datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) + delta)
    return datetime.now()
```

Но я постоянно получаю ошибку

```
$ py /g/Licensy/bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:/Licensy/bot.py", line 8, in <module>
from database_handler import DatabaseHandler
File "G:\Licensy\database_handler.py", line 7, in <module>
from helpers import licence_helper
File "G:\Licensy\helpers\licence_helper.py", line 46
datetime.now() = (datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) + delta)
^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Без изменения функции `get_current_time()` всё работает нормально, но при запуске скрипта, например, на Heroku он показывает время того часового пояса, где расположен сервер.

В чем заключается ошибка?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-to-convert-local-time-string-to-utc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты пытаешься присвоить значение функции, т.е. переопределить функцию импортируемого модуля. Нужно же просто вернуть значение с дельтой

```
def get_current_time() -> datetime:
    delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=3, minutes=0)
    return datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) + delta
```